# Why does the current in autotransformer motor starting gets reduced squared in relative to the voltage?

Tags: motor, autotransformer

Say, relatively, the motor's full voltage rating's voltage, current and torque are 100, 100 and 100

Why does when the autotransformer tap is set at 80%, the motor runs at

80 64 64

65% and 50% as follows:

65 42 42

50 25 25

And not operating in direct proportion to the voltage?

Edit: The motor is just a 3phase AC induction motor in general

Comment: Torque proportional to current so that makes sense.  I wonder what the phase relation between V and I looks like?

Comment: This isn't an auto transformer question, it's a question about induction motors and lowering the voltage supply and measuring current and torque

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry I don't quite follow, is there anything I need to change in the OP?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold This is just a statement in general, no specific values needed to be known, unless accounting for the losses.
Here's a random answer on the internet that I found, but don't quite grasp what it means (only comment #1 is relevant)
http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=105696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current *in the motor* scales linearly with voltage *at the motor*. However, *at the transformer input* the current is scaled down by the transformer ratio a second time.

So if the transformer ratio is X, the motor voltage is V<sub>LINE</sub> × X. The motor current is I<sub>NOMINAL</sub> × X, and the power is V<sub>LINE</sub> × I<sub>NOMINAL</sub> × X<sup>2</sup>.

To get the value of the line current at the input of the transformer, divide the power by the line voltage, and you're left with I<sub>NOMINAL</sub> × X<sup>2</sup>.